# Ruby Shopify CLI installation - missing libraries - error

Tags: ruby, windows, shopify

I am fairly new to Ruby and getting an error in the command line when attempting to use it to [install Shopify CLI](https://shopify.dev/apps/tools/cli/installation)  `gem install shopify-cli`.

I verified that I have ruby installed by running `ruby -v`
[image: ruby version screenshot git bash]

Here is the error:

```
C:\Users\mso87>gem install shopify-cli
```

Fetching rb-fsevent-0.11.0.gem
Fetching rb-inotify-0.10.1.gem
Fetching ffi-1.15.3-x64-mingw32.gem
Fetching listen-3.6.0.gem
Fetching liquid-5.0.1.gem
Fetching nokogiri-1.12.3-x64-mingw32.gem
Fetching nokogumbo-2.0.5.gem
Fetching theme-check-1.2.0.gem
Fetching shopify-cli-2.2.2.gem
Successfully installed rb-fsevent-0.11.0
Successfully installed ffi-1.15.3-x64-mingw32
Successfully installed rb-inotify-0.10.1
Successfully installed listen-3.6.0
Successfully installed liquid-5.0.1
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing shopify-cli:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
current directory: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/racc-1.5.2/ext/racc/cparse
```

C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20210816-16376-5tlz85.rb extconf.rb
checking for rb_ary_subseq()... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError) You have to install development tools first. from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:552:in` try_link0'
from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:570:in `try_link' from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:782:in` try_func'
from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1069:in `block in have_func' from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:959:in` block in checking_for'
from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block (2 levels) in postpone' from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in` open'
from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block in postpone' from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in` open'
from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:357:in `postpone' from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:958:in` checking_for'
from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1068:in `have_func' from extconf.rb:6:in` '

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.6.0/racc-1.5.2/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/racc-1.5.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.6.0/racc-1.5.2/gem_make.out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs for shopify cli mention that you need ruby 2.7 installed on your system. From looking at your output, you're using ruby 2.6.

https://shopify.dev/apps/tools/cli/installation

Comment: This did the trick! I installed  Ruby+Devkit 2.7.4-1 (x64) 
 from https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ - thanks!